# Very simple PHP MySQLi query with multiple values

Tags: php, html

I need to convert a MySQL query into a MySQLi and I need some hint with the code.

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT parameter1, parameter2 FROM table WHERE id = X;
```

I have a PHP sentence where I have to use the two parameters, something like this:

```
echo "With the X id the parameter 1 is: ". $parameter1 ." and the parameter2 is ". $parameter2;
```

I know it is a trivial question but I am new to PHP coding and I will really appreciate who ever wants to lend me a hand. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The actual query string will be the same. Just the way you call it will be different.

Comment: "lend me a hand" is an euphemism for "write a code for me"?

Comment: What is the question here?? query string doesn't change in MySQL or MySQLi.

Comment: @Your Common Snese, it's not. It's a way of saying "point me in the right direction: read this, search for [TERM], go to this link", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
  }
$check=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT parameter1,parameter2 FROM table WHERE id='x'");
  $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
$parameter1=$row['parameter1'];
$parameter2=$row['parameter2'];
echo "With the X id the parameter 1 is: $parameter1 and the parameter2 is $parameter2";

?>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect! DO I still need to put the mysqli_close() at the end?

Comment: Yes if you want to close the connection. Mark as Answer

Answer (score 1):

Quickly copied and pasted from http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should, you may be interested in this:

```
$DBServer = 'server name or IP address'; // e.g 'localhost' or '192.168.1.100'
$DBUser   = 'DB_USER';
$DBPass   = 'DB_PASSWORD';
$DBName   = 'DB_NAME';

$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$sql='SELECT parameter1, parameter2 FROM table WHERE id = X';

$rs=$conn->query($sql);

if($rs === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$rs->data_seek(0);
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "With the X id the parameter 1 is: ". $row['parameter1'] ." and the parameter2 is ". $row['parameter2'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try to use that.

Comment: added more info for connecting.  all of this is available at the site i posted